# Use datasets from different locations and different projects in DBT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

I do know you can configure your default desired location in the profiles.yaml

```yaml
default:
  target: default
  outputs:
    default:
      type: bigquery
      method: oauth
      dataset: default_dataset
      location: europe-west1
```

But then all the rest of the defined sources (Bigquery Datasets in my case) will have this same location. So I could not query a dataset located in `europe-east2` anymore in this project

```yaml
version: 2
sources:
  - name: dataset_in_asia_location
    tables:
      - name: incremental_table
```

There's nothing in the documentation for the sources ([props](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/source-properties) nor [configs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/source-configs))

So, how do you use a dbt source from a diferent location that the default one defined in the profiles.yaml?

Comment: If you set your dbt profile location to "EU" (multi-region) and then run the following, what do you get for the location column?

`SELECT schema_name, location FROM \`<my-project>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA\``

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of DBT](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/bigquery-profile#execution-project) states that DBT will use the default location unless you specify a custom project/database config.

```
my-profile:
 target: dev
 outputs:
   dev:
     type: bigquery
     method: oauth
     project: abc-123
     dataset: my_dataset
```

Additionally, in the `.yaml` location, it is recommended to use [multi-region](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#multi-regions) locations.

Comment: Thanks @Jose,  I do understand this too. Issue is when you have to mix/query data from datasets from different locations (dataset_1 in EU, dataset_2 in europe-west1)

Comment: @dinigo That's correct. That is why DBT recommends to use multi-region datasets or to use the amount of datasets on the same location.